# Using jquery autocomplete to retrieve value from key (label) value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I would like some help with the following.
I have a list of names (places) and their coordinates as follows:

```
var data = [
    {"label":"Zurich", "coords":"25.674847,85.025781"},
    {"label":"Antwerp", "coords":"23.765237,-102.875977"},
    {"label":"Some place", "coords":"38.425865,44.874582"},
    ];
```

I have implemented an autocompleted text box where the user types the first letters of the place and gets the matching labels. What I would like to do, however, is this: when the user selects a place, zurich for example, to retrieve the corresponding coords for zurich and store them in a variable. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to the `select` event:

```
$('.elem').autocomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var coords = ui.item.coords;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate through your data and then get the coords for the label-value.